# Node.js command-line variable not recognized

Tags: node.js, cmd

I'm currently following a node.js course on skillshare, which works with a config file to determine what port a http or https server should run on. To do this, the variable "NODE_ENV" is being passed via the command-line at runtime. The value of this variable in turn determines what port the server runs on.

I've copied the code from the course's github, this way it shouldn't be a fault in the code.

However, when I try to pass the variable through with the exact same command as the video shows (`NODE_ENV=production node index.js`), I get an error:

`'NODE_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

The only difference between me and the course should be that I'm working on Windows (10), while they are working on a MacBook.

I've tried including the `NODE_ENV` variable behind the `node index.js`, but this didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works differently on Windows.

Try the following:

```
SET NODE_ENV=production
node index.js
```

This setup might solve your problem.